# NestJs TypoORM wont connect to DB when inside a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Nestjs server I am trying to run in a docker container and I am also trying to run a local version of a mysql database as well. I am using docker compose to keep them on the same network.

Here is the error I am getting

> server_1    | [Nest] 41  - 08/24/2022, 2:20:22 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)...
> server_1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
> server_1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)

I am new to docker but have been trying to copy tutorials exactly and still cant figure out why this wont work.

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/server-workdir
      - '/server-workdir/node_modules'
    depends_on:
      - local_db
  
  local_db:
    container_name: "local_db"
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=local
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

Here is the dockerfile for my server

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /server-workdir

COPY package.json /server-workdir
RUN yarn install

COPY . /server-workdir/

RUN yarn run build


VOLUME [ "/server-workdir/node_modules" ]

CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

Here is the app config for my nest app (minus any sensitive info)

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [config]
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: "mysql",
      host: "local_db",
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: [],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([SeederHistory]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRY_TIME },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: JwtAuthGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useClass: ValidationPipe,
    },
    SeederService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

here is the .env file

```
PORT="8000"
DB_HOST = "local_db"
DB_PORT = "3306"
DB_USERNAME = "root"
DB_PASSWORD = "root"
DB_NAME = "local"
JWT_EXPIRY_TIME = "2d"
HASH_ROUNDS = "14"
JWT_SECRET = "testSecret"
```

This does run locally (not using a docker container), really unsure what is wrong here, docker is still new to me

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, instead of using `localhost`, replace it with `host.docker.internal`